# In Android what happens to a File when the app crashes elsewhere during a write?

Tags: android, file, crash, outputstream

Lets say I have a background task that writes a random letter to a file through an FileOutputStream every 5s. After 1 min the stream will close and the task will stop. Let's say the app then crashes 30s in on the UI thread, maybe from an NPE, and we never get to close the stream.

Does the File save what we have already written to it? Or do we lose everything?

Comment: Edited my question. Going with FileOutputStream

Comment: Did you buffer it?  That is, did you wrap it with something which has buffering ... like BufferedOutputStream, or a few other classes?

Comment: Hoestly, haven't actually done anything with it. This is an extremely contrived example. Use case is significantly more complicated than this. This was sort of a random edge case that came to mind. It appears it depends on the implementation and how it handles buffering

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which implementation of [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) you are using, as it is an abstract class. The method which actually interacts with the file system and writes something to a file is flush().

For example, [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) has the capability to flush automatically every time it is written to.

**EDIT:** FileOutputStream isn't wrapped in any buffering functionality, therefore it should write each letter immediately to your file; the file will persist with your letters in it after the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I think will depend on whether the character(s) you send to the stream are still in the stream memory buffer.  Most streams will use some kind of memory buffer for performance reasons.  A common pattern in exception handling for IO code is to call close() on the stream in a finally{} block to ensure stream is closed (and flushed) whether or not an exception happens.

Comment: If you are going to recommend `close()` in `finally`, then "try with resources" is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: I guess you missed the part about "crash". You don't get to call close when your app abruptly crashes.